# Mesh deformation with Curve Modifer

Tags: bezier-curves

Can anyone tell me why the mesh I am trying to Array & Deform along this curve changes scale so dramatically when I apply the curve modifier?

Origins are matching and scale/rotation are applied to all objects so why does the "cross section" shrink?

Many thanks
Pootle

[image]

Comment: Can you show image of how "this curve changes scale so dramatically" ? I don't see any problems with applying modifiers, the objects continue staying intact.

Comment: One thing to note - make sure you apply modifiers from top of the stack to the bottom. So in this case you should apply **Array** first and only then proceed to applying **Curve** modifier.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should do is apply the array modifier and delete the curve modifier from the mesh, in that order. Next, add a new bezier curve and rotate it 90 degrees on the y axis. Then switch to the object data panel for the bezier curve. Under shape, change `Preview U:` resolution to 64 (its max).

Then, drag the bottom of the curve over to the bottom of your mesh. This doesn't have to be exact, only pretty close. After that, key `Shift+Ctrl+Alt+C` and chose Origin to 3D cursor. Then scale down the curve to the height of the original curve. `Tab` into edit mode, and key `A` to select all and `W` to show a pop-up menu. Select subdivide. Now using vertex snap and your own adjustments, match the new curve to the shape of the old curve. After you are satisfied, delete the old curve.

Lastly, add a curve modifier to your mesh and select the bezier curve. Set the deformation axis to x. Moving your mesh along the z axis will make it follow the curve.

Hope this helps and happy Blending!

Comment: Update: It is because you applied the scale and rotation to the curve that this issue occurred. If you could find out a way to unapply that, then that would be a simpler solution, but I do not believe that exists.